# Magento 2 : How can I check email exists or not in form input

Tags: magento2

### I'm new to magento 2, please help me..

### How can I check email exists or not in form input

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="email">Enter an email address: </label>
<input id="email" />
<h2 id="result"></h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const validateEmail = (email) => {
  return email.match(
    /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
  );
};

const validate = () => {
  const $result = $('#result');
  const email = $('#email').val();
  $result.text('');

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $result.text(email + ' is valid :)');
    $result.css('color', 'green');
  } else {
    $result.text(email + ' is not valid :(');
    $result.css('color', 'red');
  }
  return false;
}

$('#email').on('input', validate);
</script>
```

[image]

[image]